# Is there a set of guidelines or advices for switching a `malloc()` implementation from using `sbrk()` to `mmap()`?

Tags: c, malloc

I am working on an embedded system that contains some of its own memory management code. This code works when compiled with uClibc however modern C libraries like musl disable `sbrk()`. What do I need to know to start rewriting a `sbrk()` based `malloc()` implementation into an `mmap()` based one.

Comment: Doug Lea's `malloc()` page has a [detailed discussion of this](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html). It is worth reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several months ago I had to code a malloc implementation as an assignment. I followed [this very good tutorial](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) that, unfortunately, used brk and sbrk to code simple malloc, free and realloc functions, while I had to use mmap to code my malloc, free and realloc. If I remember well, those are the things I noticed between mmap and sbrk :

**Thou shalt keep track of your allocations**

Calling sbrk with a 0 value gives you the current location of the program break. mmap doesn't work like that. Like malloc, a mmap call returns a pointer to a newly allocated zone. And you will have to stock that pointer somewhere. If you allocate several zones, you will have to keep track of all of them, with "handmade" linked lists as described in the above tutorial.

**Thou shalt use mmap wisely**

mmap is a system call, and a quite slow one. It allocates huge memory pages (a multiple of the default page size of your system, (that might be 4096 bytes). To avoid too many calls to mmap, you will have to allocate a big chunk of memory, and divide it into tiny chunks for your program allocations. Again, read the above tutorial. For my assignment, the trick was to create three mmap' ed "zones". One for tiny allocations, one for medium-sized allocations, big allocations were made with one call to mmap. All this for efficiency and optimization.

**Thou shalt munmap your mmap's**

If you don't use a mmap'ed zone anymore, that means if all its chunks of memory are not used, you must give it back to the system with the munmap() system call. And to do it efficiently you must pass the pointer to the beginning of the mmap'ed zone to do it. Hence the importance of keeping track of your allocations.

Hope this helps you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code and particularly **point `#7`** of [malloc(), free(), realloc() using brk() and sbrk()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80190/malloc-free-realloc-using-brk-and-sbrk)'s review may give you a good starting point :)

*(As I'm researching a similar topic myself, I'll try to keep a list of (what I think are) useful links in here.)*

- [Tips of malloc & free: Making your own malloc library for troubleshooting](http://elinux.org/images/b/b5/Elc2013_Kobayashi.pdf): a beginner-friendly presentation
- [Inside memory management: *The choices, tradeoffs, and implementations of dynamic allocation*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-memory/): a step by step guide to implementing a `sbrk()`-based `malloc()` and replacing the standard one (`LD_PRELOAD`)
- [A Quick Tutorial on Implementing and Debugging Malloc, Free, Calloc, and Realloc](http://danluu.com/malloc-tutorial/): a walk-through of a [publicly-available](https://github.com/danluu/malloc-tutorial) implementation of `malloc()`